# With her enhanced durability and resistance, is Rogue capable of getting physically sick?

Tags: x-men, mutant, powers, rogue

Rogue from the X-men is a  utant with the ability to take bio-energy, and thus powers, from other mutants and super beings. At her *base,* though, while mutant, her genome is still essentially human. This was enhanced when she permanently absorbed the powers of Carol Danvers as her initial Ms. Marvel form, which was essentially a combination of human and *Kree* DNA. I don't know if the Kree are susceptible to earth-born illnesses, so would that make Rogue now immune to them as well?

Better yet: Outside of something purposefully designed, like the Legacy virus, has it been shown in comic that Rogue can catch a cold? Or does her enhanced resistance to damage *also* protect her from some pathogens? Are there any comics which can show this?